# Scala - convert Set[(x,y]) to Set[y]

Tags: scala

Currently I have this Set collection:

```
Set((S00002,3), (S00001,2), (S00001,1), (S00003,4))
```

Is there any good way to convert it to something like this:

```
Set(3,2,1,4)
```

Below is my current code to produce above Set[(String,Long)]:

```
data.expense_items.groupBy(i => (i.supplier_id, i.po_id)).mapValues( _.map ( j => j.price)).keys
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `map` method:

```
val s = Set(("S00002",3), ("S00001",2), ("S00001",1), ("S00003",4))
s.map(_._2) // Set(3, 2, 1, 4)
```

Comment: Fool me, I tried `_._2.mkString()`, forgot to `map` it first then use `.mkString`. BTW, I want to sort the result but I can't use `sortBy` since it gives me value this error `sortBy is not a member of Iterable[Long]`.

Comment: @user26409021 convert result to any `seq` and sort it.

Answer (score 1):

Several other approaches,

```
mySet.collect { case (_,v) => v }

mySet.unzip._2

for ( (_,v) <- mySet ) yield v

mySet.toMap.values.toSet
```